# error: binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two '[Int : String]' operands

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to add a a value to an array, but I keep coming up with this error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to add a literal and an integer? I need to define this? How would I go about doing that.

```
var numberDictionary = [1 : "one", 2 : "two", 3 : "three", 4 : "four"]
// Add 5 : "five" to this dictionary
// WORK HERE

numberDictionary += [5 : "five"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this instead:

```
numberDictionary[5] = "five"
```

Also, dictionaries are called dictionaries not arrays.

Comment: This will append [5 : "five"] to the end of the numberDictionary?

Comment: Dictionaries, like sets, are not ordered, so it makes no sense to add to the end of a dictionary. If you want ordered dictionaries, you have to use a list of pairs or something.